# Nginx: hide (mask/change) email addresses in requests in access logs

Tags: nginx

How can we hide (mask/change) email addresses in requests in NGINX access logs:

```
"30/Aug/2018:09:55:59 +0000" client=x.x.x.x method=GET request="GET /api/........?username=daffy.duck@customer.com HTTP/1.1" request_length=986 status=200 ....
```

If it is possible:

```
daffy.duck@customer.com -> d.d@mycompony.com
```

or

```
daffy.duck@customer.com -> ****@****
```

Comment: Your API is badly designed. Those need to be POST requests.

Comment: You're right, I understand that. But I am not a developer, only sysops. And at the moment I have to hide emails

Comment: I know of no way to do that in nginx, without turning off logging entirely. Or, at least, not logging these specific requests.

Comment: You might want to take a look into nginx Lua scripting and check if you can create logging function over there, which would remove parts of URLs according to some rules.